# Integrate the electronjs application inside the Wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, electron

I have WPF application in that i want to render the electronjs app inside the window frame. actually, I am able to load electronjs application but as separate application not in window frame.
Please find below code:

```
{
 process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"xyz.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-parentHWND " + hWnd.ToInt32() + " " + 
                Environment.CommandLine;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();

                process.WaitForInputIdle();
}
```

Comment: Electron app are Desktop apps, so how can you load it inside of a window? Do you just mean to load the webapp that your Electron app points to in some frame?